# mqTranslate code in theme template

Tags: php, wordpress

Tried to lookup the mqtranslate related questions but none of them answer my question, so I ask here.

I tried to add custom menu in the WordPress header instead using its own menu, I installed the mqtranslate and adding the code to define the menu item name for different language. I found both language text were showed no matter I switch the any one language. Below is my code in the header. I only replace the  with my code.

```
<?php
/*
 * Template Name: Custom Front Page (Debug use)
 */
?>
<!doctype html>
<!--[if IE 8]> <html class="no-js lt-ie9" <?php language_attributes(); ?>> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" <?php language_attributes(); ?>> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title><?php ci_e_title(); ?></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <?php // JS files are loaded via /functions/scripts.php ?>

    <?php // CSS files are loaded via /functions/styles.php ?>

    <?php wp_head(); ?>

</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<?php do_action('after_open_body_tag'); ?>

<?php
if ( !is_page_template('template-front.php') ) {
    echo '<div id="bg"></div>';
}
?>

<div id="page">
    <header id="header" class="row">
        <div class="twelve columns">
            <div class="wrap">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="three columns">
                        <div id="logo" class="<?php logo_class(); ?>">
                            <?php ci_e_logo('<h1>', '</h1>'); ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="nine columns">
                        <nav id="hoz-menu">
                            <ul id="hoz-menu" class="topmenu">
                                <li class="topfirst"><a href="javascript:void()" style="height:32px;line-height:32px;"><span><!--:cn-->Simplified Chinese text here<!--:--><!--:tw-->Traditional Chinese test here<!--:--></span></a>
```

... ( rest content omitted ) ....

Answer (score 2):

by calling php function

_e("Simplified Chinese text hereTraditional Chinese test here");

```
<div class="nine columns">
                        <nav id="hoz-menu">
                            <ul id="hoz-menu" class="topmenu">
                                <li class="topfirst"><a href="javascript:void()" style="height:32px;line-height:32px;"><span>**<?php _e("<!--:cn-->Simplified Chinese text here<!--:--><!--:tw-->Traditional Chinese test here<!--:-->"); ?>**</span></a>
```